# How do I predict values using ltsReg of robustbase package in R?

Tags: r, linear-regression, regression-testing

The stats predict function doesn't read "lts" method. I know that package MASS has a function called lqs (with method lts), so as to run robust regression and a predictions, but the parameters obtained from MASS are different from ltsReg. Which one should I use? Am i doing something wrong?

I've been using ltsReg, in order to detect outliers and study the difference between the linear and robust approach and it has been good. Therefore, it will be better keep on working and finding a way to predict with ltsReg than start all the stuff again in MASS lqs function.

```
data(coleman)
fool.1 <- ltsReg(Y ~ ., data = coleman)
summary(fool.1)`
Call:
ltsReg.formula(formula = Y ~ ., data = coleman)

Residuals (from reweighted LS):
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-1.2155 -0.3887  0.0000  0.3056  0.9845 

Coefficients:
          Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
Intercept 29.75772    5.53224   5.379 0.000166 ***
salaryP   -1.69854    0.46602  -3.645 0.003358 ** 
fatherWc   0.08512    0.02079   4.093 0.001490 ** 
sstatus    0.66617    0.03824  17.423 6.94e-10 ***
teacherSc  1.18400    0.16425   7.208 1.07e-05 ***
motherLev -4.06675    0.84867  -4.792 0.000440 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 0.7824 on 12 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-Squared: 0.9883, Adjusted R-squared: 0.9835 
F-statistic: 203.2 on 5 and 12 DF,  p-value: 3.654e-11
here

fool.2 <- lqs(Y ~ ., data = coleman, method = "lts)
fool.2$coefficients




(Intercept)     salaryP    fatherWc     sstatus   teacherSc   motherLev 
20.45608974 -0.03680888  0.04687359  0.61946444  0.81382027 -1.52285563
```

Comment: If you look at the documentation of ltsReg, it's stated in the notes that you should use `lmrob()` instead of ltsReg. `lmrob` does have a predict method.

Comment: Yes, I saw, but I need to do some simulations with lts algorithm like in Peter J. Rousseeuw's book. I know that exist lots of contributions after this book, but I have to study this algorithm specifically.